My .Net Maui app doesn't get the correct Reason Phrase from the http request in IOS
Im having this issue with my maui app for a while now. Whenever I execute a http request that has a 400 status code response it works fine in Android and testing the endpoint manually from postman, the issue is when i run it in IOS. here's an example
this is the result when executing the app on android
and this is the result when running it on IOS
this is the code im using to make the http request
protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync<T>(string path, T payload, bool useAuth)
{
    var dataToPost = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);
    var content = new StringContent(dataToPost, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    if (useAuth) SetAuthorizationHeader();

    var relativeUri = Constants.GetAuthPath(useAuth) + path;
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(_httpClient.BaseAddress, relativeUri), content);
    EnsureSuccessResponse(response);

    return response;
}

I have worked around the issue by setting personalized messages, but I would like a better solution

Is ReasonPhrase: 'Password does not meet... default error message or your custom?
